# How to convert Java objects to XML element attributes using JAXB

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jaxb, marshalling

How to convert java object to xml using `JAXB` to get the following xml:

```
<Case>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <Code>457123</Code>
  <Meta uc=\"Sample\" pip=\"116.0.1.1\" lot=\"P\"/>
</Case>
```

There are many answers regarding how to get XML. I have gone through all those. But my question is how to get the XML as what I have shown. It contains a self-closing tag which even contains attributes.

I am using Eclipse IDE. Please suggest a method.

This is my case class:

```
import auth.Res.Meta;

@XmlRootElement (name="Case")

public class Test {

private Meta mt;
private String version;
private String code;

@XmlRootElement
public class Meta {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String uc;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String pip;

    public String getUc() {
        return uc;
    }

    public void setUc(String uc) {
        this.uc = uc;
    }

    public String getPip() {
        return pip;
    }

    public void setPip(String pip) {
        this.pip = pip;
    }
}

public Meta getMt() {
    return mt;
}

public void setMt(Meta mt) {
    this.mt = mt;
}

public String getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
}
```

Solution:

I solved it by creating seperate class for Meta as suggested by LazerBanana in the first answer.

Comment: please do some research there are at least 20 answers in stack about [marshaling java to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797838/convert-java-object-using-jaxb-to-xml-and-vice-versa-marshal-and-unmarshal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert java object using jaxb to xml and vice versa (marshal and unmarshal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797838/convert-java-object-using-jaxb-to-xml-and-vice-versa-marshal-and-unmarshal)

Comment: yes .there are many answers. i have gone through all those. But my question is how to get the xml as what i have shown. It contains a self closing tag which evn contains attributes.

Comment: please consider explaining that in the question then and give us the [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: is there any way to create like this..pls give a solution

Comment: add Case class to the question

Comment: I have added the case class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your Meta class should look like.

```
public class Meta {

    private String uc;
    private String pip;
    private String lot;

    public String getUc() {
        return uc;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setUc(String uc) {
        this.uc = uc;
    }

    public String getPip() {
        return pip;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setPip(String pip) {
        this.pip = pip;
    }

    public String getLot() {
        return lot;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setLot(String lot) {
        this.lot = lot;
    }
}
```

this is your Case class which is the root element

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Case {

    private int version;
    private String code;
    private String id;
    private Meta meta;

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Meta getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }
}
```

And this is the marshaling bit to the console and to the file it you want.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Case fcase = new Case();
        Meta meta = new Meta();

        meta.setLot("asd");
        meta.setPip("sdafa");
        meta.setUc("asgd4");

        fcase.setMeta(meta);
        fcase.setVersion(1);
        fcase.setId("sah34");
        fcase.setCode("code34");

        try {

//            File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Case.class, Meta.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

//            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(fcase, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(fcase, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
<case>
  <code>code34</code>
  <id>sah34</id>
  <meta lot="asd" pip="sdafa" uc="asgd4"/>
  <version>1</version>
</case>
```

Next time please try to do more research i am not an expert and I just googled it.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: i need to get all these in a single class..so that i can create a single object to set all

Comment: may i know - why ?

Comment: i have added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

i need to create a rest service which accepts xml of  format i have gien. Thats y i need it in a single class.

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")

public Response getper(Test test)
{
String nam=test.getVersion();
int cd=test.getCode();
Res rs=new Res();
rs.setMessage(nam);
.
.



 return Response.status(200).entity(rs).build();

}
```

Comment: Then try to find answers for your questions on stack, nobody is going to do all work for you, if you can't ask the proper question even. I have tried and spent enough time here, sorry, I wish you luck.

Comment: @LazerBanana I am really sorry to waste ur time.  this is wat i really meant.. i know to create xml using different classes.. what i need was in a single. and my case class shows the same