# Convert java object to xml with accordingly type

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, marshalling

When I convert an object to xml, i get the result without specifying the appropriate field types, for example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "User")
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
class User: {
    var name: String? = null
    var age: Int? = null
}

fun toXML(obj: User): String {
        val marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(User::class.java).createMarshaller()
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true)
        val stringWriter = StringWriter()
        marshaller.marshal(obj, stringWriter)
        return stringWriter.toString()
    }
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>44</age>
</user>
```

Desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
    <name type="String">John</name>
    <age type="Integer">44</age>
</user>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: [Refer this link, possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716923/how-to-convert-java-objects-to-xml-element-attributes-using-jaxb)

Comment: You are going to need to use @XmlAttribute for that, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514752/xml-element-with-attribute-and-content-using-jaxb/5515787) for instance. But isn't this what you use an Xml Schema for?

Comment: When i save User to database other system (IBM BPM) can't parse object without types.

Comment: I took a quick look at IBM BPM and it is a Java application so I would be very surprised if it couldn’t make use of XML Schemas when parsing Xml

Answer (score 1):

In user class annotate `name` , `age` with `@XmlAttribute`

```
@XmlAttribute
protected String name;

@XmlAttribute
protected Integer age;
```

A brief Tutorial is available here: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

> A quick recall of below mentioned Annotations can ease a lot of work:

| @XmlSchema       | Maps a Java package to an XML namespace.

| @XmlAccessorType | Defines the fields and properties of your Java classes that the JAXB engine uses for binding. It has four values: PUBLIC_MEMBER, FIELD, PROPERTY and NONE.

| @XmlAccessOrder  | Defines the sequential order of the children.

| @XmlType         | Maps a Java class to a schema type. It defines the type name and order of its children.

| @XmlRootElement  | Defines the XML root element. Root Java classes need to be registered with the JAXB context when it is created.

| @XmlElement      | Maps a field or property to an XML element

| @XmlAttribute    | Maps a field or property to an XML attribute

| @XmlTransient    | Prevents mapping a field or property to the XML Schema

| @XmlValue        | Maps a field or property to the text value on an XML tag.

| @XmlList         | Maps a collection to a list of values separated by space.

Comment: Thanks for help! Result is :  <User name="John" age="44"/>. Field type is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

try with following POJOs,
create separate POJO classes for `name` and `age`.

User.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="user")
public class  User {

    @XmlElement
    private Name name;

    @XmlElement
    private Age age;

    // set getters and setters

}
```

Name.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="name")
public class  Name {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    // set getters and setters

}
```

Age.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="age")
public class  Age {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    @XmlValue
    private int value;

    // set getters and setters

}
```

set the values to objects,

```
User user = new User();

Name name = new Name();
name.setType("String");
name.setValue("John");

Age age = new Age();
age.setType("Integer");
age.setValue("44");

user.setName(name);
user.setAge(age);
```

unmarshalling with JAXB, it gets following expected output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user> 
    <name type="String">John</name>
    <age type="Integer">44</age>
</user>
```

Comment: It will work. But this is not a prod solution, because if an object contains many fields, there are too many overheads